# Authorize.Net - including order in transactionRequestType causes charge to fail (c#)

Tags: c#, authorize.net

This is very easy to duplicate for me, it's as simple as including or not including a few lines in the following example.

```
customerProfilePaymentType transProfile = new customerProfilePaymentType
{
    customerProfileId = _custProfileId,
    paymentProfile = new paymentProfile { paymentProfileId = _paymentProfileId }
};

transactionRequestType trans = new transactionRequestType
{
    transactionType = transactionTypeEnum.authCaptureTransaction.ToString(),
    amount = TotalAmount,
    profile = transProfile,
    order = new orderType 
    { 
        description = "Test Description", 
        invoiceNumber = "Invoice #" 
    }
};

createTransactionRequest chargeReq = new createTransactionRequest { transactionRequest = trans };

createTransactionController chargeCntl = new createTransactionController(chargeReq);
chargeCntl.Execute();

_chargeResp = chargeCntl.GetApiResponse();
```

Ok .. so this one is simple. At the end of this code the value of _chargeResp is null. However, if I just comment out the 5 lines starting with "order = new orderType" then the code runs just fine.

I'm probably just not understanding something here, so hopefully someone can point me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer but I don't have enough rep to just comment. I'm guessing it had something else to do with your setup since my sandbox test just worked for me (though I'm using equivalent VB syntax rather than C#).

```
Dim transactionRequest = New transactionRequestType() With { _
     .transactionType = transactionTypeEnum.authCaptureTransaction.ToString(), _
     .amount = amount, _
     .payment = paymentType, _
     .billTo = billingAddress, _
     .order = New orderType With { _
        .description = "Test Description", _
        .invoiceNumber = "Invoice #" _
        } _
}
```

Those 2 lines in the confirmation email had the info I sent as well:

========= ORDER INFORMATION =========
Invoice : Invoice #
Description : Test Description
Amount : 56.22 (USD)
Payment Method: Visa xxxx1111
Transaction Type: Authorization and Capture

Comment: I've been pulled to a different product temporarily, but that's still a hot topic here. Thanks for the info, at least I know it's not the code (or at least doesn't seem to be).